# Three points are collinear iff the determinant of the matrix of their barycentric coordinates vanishes

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry, barycentric-coordinates

Let $A,B,C\in \mathbb{R}^2$ be noncollinear points. Then we have that for every point $P\in\mathbb{R}^2$ there exist $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $P=\alpha_1A+\alpha_2 B+\alpha_3 C$, and $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3=1$ (I've already proven that).

Now, write $P_1,P_2,P_3\in\mathbb{R}^2$ in the above coordinates :$$P_i=\alpha_{i1}A+\alpha_{i2}B+\alpha_{i3}C, \qquad i=1,2,3,$$ 
with
$$\alpha_{i1}+\alpha_{i2}+\alpha_{i3}  =1.$$ 
Then I must prove that:

> The points $P_1,P_2,P_3$ are collinear iff $\det(a_{ij})=0$.

For $\Rightarrow$, I supposed that they are collinear, in which case $P_3-P_1$ and $P_2-P_1$ are linearly dependent. I tried to express these given the coordinates, it became too long and then I got lost. But I think there must be a better way to prove it.

So, any idea?

Comment: Collinearity is preserved by affine transformations, and one can choose an affine transformation that maps $A, B, C$ resp. to, e.g., $(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1)$, so we may as well assume that $A, B, C$ are those points. Then, a point $P_i(x_i, y_i)$ has barycentric coordinates $$\alpha_{i1} = -x_i - y_i + 1, \quad \alpha_{i2} = x_i, \quad \alpha_{i3} = y_i.$$

Comment: Oh, using an affine transformation would help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I've upgraded my comment to a proper answer, since it contains a real hint anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Since (1) collinearity is preserved by affine transformations and (2) one can choose an affine transformation that maps $A, B, C$ as given resp. to, e.g., $(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1)$, we may as well assume that $A, B, C$ are those points.

(To see the latter, note that we can apply the translation that maps $A$ to the origin and then apply the linear transformation with matrix $\pmatrix{\bar{B}&\bar{C}}^{-1}$, where $\bar{B}, \bar{C}$ are resp. the images of $B, C$ under that translation, regarded as column vectors.)

Then, for any point $P_i(x_i, y_i)$, solving the given system defining the barycentric coordinates $\alpha_{ij}$ is easy:
$$\alpha_{i1} = -x_i - y_i + 1, \qquad \alpha_{i2} = x_i, \qquad \alpha_{i3} = y_i.$$